# Dockerfile filepaths: what does the colon mean?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In Dockerfiles and docker-compose files I often stumble across two notations.

Example docker-compose:

```
volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
```

Example Dockerfile

```
COPY ./Pipfile /usr/src/app/Pipfile
```

The second one means, take the file/folder from my machines directory ./Pipfile and Copy it to the image in the directory /usr/...? But what does the first one mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: https://docs.docker.com/storage/images/types-of-mounts-volume.png]

In the case of a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

> `-v` or `--volume`: Consists of three fields, separated by colon characters (`:`).
>   The fields must be in the correct order, and the meaning of each field is not immediately obvious.
>
> - In the case of bind mounts, the first field is the path to the file or directory on the host machine.
> - The second field is the path where the file or directory is mounted in the container.
> - The third field is optional, and is a comma-separated list of options, such as ro, consistent, delegated, cached, z, and Z. These options are discussed below.

In case of **named volume**: **the first field is the name of the volume**, and is unique on a given host machine. For anonymous volumes, the first field is omitted.

Here: the first argument is a path, /app/: so bind mount it is.

Comment: your answer got me further in understanding this, thanks! I am no just completely confused as to what this is a bind mount? As far as my understanding goes right now, both volumes and bind mounts are specified using the volume keyword ...

Comment: @Xen_mar Yes. I have edited my answer to include the named volume case.

Comment: Ah, absolutely awesome. I was just about to write another comment, since i've gotten a little further. Quite confusing that the only difference in declaring is the name as the first field. Thank you very much for explaining this to me!